# How to use Angular PrimeNG MenuItem badge property?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Even when I set badge and badgeStyleClass to the menu item's model, nothing happen! Is there anyone who used this feature?

It seens to be very simple, but only show up label text no badge:

```
          this.items = [
            {
              label: 'ambiente',
              badge: '2'
            }
          ];
```

Using version:
"primeng": "^11.0.0-rc.1"

The [documentation](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/menumodel) of MenuModel API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

badge & badgeStyleClass in menu item are only supported in premium templates of primeNg.

Have a look at the comments here - https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/commit/2f8b865cf7c44af151285e60415817c980c7fce2

Comment: It seens to be the correct anwser but there is no word about it on documentation!

Comment: True. It's poorly documented.